# Assigning an error message in Formik validation in TypeScript not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, formik

At this moment I'm trying to build a user input form where a user is supposed to enter a name, email and password, using `Formik` in React & TypeScript.

Handling inputs itself is working fine, and now I want to add validation functionality to the input form, so I wrote the code like the following.

```
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik'; 

validate(values: User){
    let errors: User; 
    errors = values
    if(!values.password){
      errors.password = 'Enter a password'
    } else if(values.password.length < 8){
      errors.password = 'Enter at least 8 characters for your password'
    }
    console.log("The length of errors.password: " + values.password.length);

    return errors;
  }

return(
      <div>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{ name, email, password }}
            onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
            validate={this.validate}
            enableReinitialize={true}
          >
            {
              (props) => (
                <Form>
                  <fieldset>
                    <label>Name</label>&nbsp;
                    <Field type="text" name="name"/>
                  </fieldset>                                   
                  <fieldset>
                    <label>Email</label>&nbsp;
                    <Field type="text" name="email"/>
                  </fieldset>
                  <ErrorMessage name="password" component="div"/>
                  <fieldset>
                    <label>Password</label>&nbsp;
                    <Field type="password" name="password"/>
                  </fieldset>
                  <button type="submit">Save</button>              
                </Form>
              )
            }      
          </Formik>
      </div>
    )
```

I wanted to show an error message depending on whether the user has entered a password whose length is long enough, but no error message shows up even when the password is too short.

I added a `console.log` in the `validation` method and made sure that the method was invoked.
When the password was long enough, like 12 characters long, the part

```
console.log("The length of errors.password: " + values.password.length);
```

is invoked and the length of the password is displayed, but when the length becomes shorter than 8, instead of assigning the string `'Enter at least 8 characters for your password'` to the `errors.password`, a warning shows up.

```
Warning: An unhandled error was caught during low priority validation in <Formik validate /> TypeError: Cannot set property 'password' of undefined
```

I looked into several GitHub pages and Stack Overflow posts, but haven't found one that seems to be related to my issue.

What am I doing wrong?

The same code was working fine in `JavaScript`, as my current version is `TypeScript` maybe there is something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `undefined` is passed as the argument to `validate` at some point during Formik's internal validation loop. I recommend changing this line:

```
let errors: User;
errors = values; // why are you assigning your error object to the values?
```

to this:

```
let errors: Partial<User> = {};
```

I'm not sure why you're assigning the current values to your error object. If there are no errors, `errors` should be an empty object (`{}`).

With the new approach, you still get type safety, because you can't assign a property to `errors` that doesn't exist in the User type:

```
errors.password = "Password too short"; // this is fine
errors.foo = "asdf"; // TypeError - No property "foo" in type "User"
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed and concrete explanation! Thanks to your advice the bug is gone :) Before I posted this question I had also tried just ```let errors: User;```, but this wasn't working and I suspected if it had something to do with initializing ```errors```. So I tried to initialize it by assigning ```values``` because I didn't know how to assign an empty object in TypeScript. The line of code ```let errors: Partial<User>``` that you suggested was exactly what I was looking for! I wish I could upvote your post 5 times.